# About google app gmail api

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, gmail-api

I was trying to send emails to my client from my application after few sent mails all mails bounces back with a message saying "You have reached a limit for sending mail. Your message was not sent."  And one more thing when i see my developer console gmail api it still showing 0% usage.what is this issue? is this a bug or something else?

Comment: If the mails are "bouncing" isn't that a problem at the recipient's end?

Comment: there are chances but the mail bounces with the message that "you have reached a limit for sending mail" means different .

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra limit on sending because it's a vector for abuse--it doesn't show up in the developers console but it's the same as sending via SMTP or the web interface.

This seems to have a good overview:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-daily-limit-sending-bulk-email/2191/